# The order of the digital contents stops at payment_review due to Redis issue

Tags: redis, 3d-secure

We have started selling the digital contents by the EC website that is created by Magento 2.4 on AWS (Multi-AZ) since a month ago.

However, it often stops the orders for the credit card in payment_review. The other payments such as Apple Pay are fine.

The symptom is as follows;

1. The problem occurs when Credit Card payment with 3D secure.
2. Rebooting Redis resolves the issue but it occurs after a day or a few days again. There is an extra free space in Redis.
3. "Did not write session for ID XXX: another process took the lock. /XXX/payment-information" sometimes occurs at the same time. (Where string XXX is a dummy string. Please ignore them.)  The parameters are max_concurrency=6,  break_after_frontend=5.

I would appreciate it if you inform me of any hints or suggestions.

2021/5/21

I would appreciate it if you could tell me any points to be careful of when we will change the value of break_after_frontend.

After the further investigation, we found that the process that process reads the session in Redis locks the session but another process has taken the session and locks the session after the break_after_frontend seconds passed. The original process failed to write the order_id into the session due to the lock by another process. Then the process has written "Did not write session for ID XXX: another process took the lock" in the log. After that the process has encountered 404 page not found error because it could not read the session data. Therefore we are thinking of changing the value of the break_after_frontend.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? We are having the same problems.